# jQuery make image popup in random position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an image randomly show up every 2 sec using jQuery. But the image always shows in a static position (top-left). I console.logged the attribute of the image and its left and top shows random px.

```js
let score = 0;
let id = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(setImage, 2000);
});

function setImage() {
  $("#container").append(
    `<img src='images/virus.gif' id='${id}' width='75px' position='absolute' class='virus' left=${randomLeft()} top=${randomTop()}/>`
  );

  $("#" + id)
    .slideUp(0)
    .fadeIn(1000);

  id++;

  $("#" + id).on("click", function (event) {
    $(event.target).remove();
    score++;
    console.log($(event.target).attr("id"), score);
  });
}

function randomTop() {
  let height = $(window).height();
  let randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 75)) + "px";
  return randomHeight;
}

function randomLeft() {
  let width = $(window).width();
  let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 75)) + "px";
  return randomLeft;
}
```

Comment: What's its z-index? Is the new image sliding up behind the old, rather than on top?

Comment: @CriticalError I wanted to implement it in a web application, but I found that the images went behind the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use style rather than left/top attributes

```
style="left:10px;right:10px"
```

Couple of other tweaks to your snippet:

- include jquery (option on the left of snippet editor adds `<script>` to the html)
- needs a `#container` to put them in, I made this `position:relative` so the `position:absolute` will work
- removed the need for the `$("#"+id)` re-finding by chaining the append
- put the `i++` at the beginning so that you don't try to attach click to something that doesn't exist yet (but doesn't matter as not used for re-finding new element)
- `$(this).remove()` must come *after* `$(this).attr("id")` - you were removing it before getting its ID
- used `this` inside the click handler rather than event.target
- would be better as `data-id=${++id}` rather than using a numerical id, but that's a small change (not made)

Updated snippet:

```js
let score = 0;
let id = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(setImage, 2000);
});

function setImage() {
  var img = $(`<img src='images/img4.jpg' id='${++id}' class='virus' style='left:${randomLeft()};top:${randomTop()}' />`);

  img.appendTo("#container")
    .slideUp(0)
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .on("click", function() {
      score++;
      console.log($(this).attr("id"), score);
      $(this).remove();
    });
}

function randomTop() {
  let height = $(window).height();
  let randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 75)) + "px";
  return randomHeight;
}

function randomLeft() {
  let width = $(window).width();
  let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 75)) + "px";
  return randomLeft;
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.virus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. Can I ask another question? I put the setInterval() into a setTimeout(), I wanted to stop the setInterval when the score hit 5. I tried to assign it to a variable, but it always triggered immediately. How should I work with that?

Comment: You should ask a new question.  But essentially, you do `var timerId = setInterval(...);` then `clearInterval(timerId)`